# sum up occupied area based on charges but exclude duplicate

Tags: excel, vba

hope you can help me about this.
i need to sum up the area of the unit that have monthly usage charges, but only add the area to the total once (some unit might have 2 charges per month, due to the charges rate change mid of the month. e,g: cell AK28 & AK29 Nov'18 charges for same unit).

[image]

the sum of the area need to be placed at row60 for every month.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using pivot tables and filter out what you need and dont need

Comment: tried. i cant just filter the duplicate lot, as the area need to be added to total area if there is usage charges apply. and same cases, a unit might have two charges for the same month, i only add the area to total area once.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best approach, but seems to work in my testing:

Formula in D9 is:

```
 =SUM(IFERROR(($C$4:$C$7*(D$4:D$7>0))
               /(COUNTIFS($B$4:$B$7,$B$4:$B$7,D$4:D$7,">0")),""))
```

applied using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (since it's an array formula).

Can then be dragged to the right.

[image]